# Stop ElementbyID onClick from running after ending the function

Tags: javascript

In the code below, when pressing the start button, a random number will generate. By clicking on the correct number (JS onClick), the score will increase by 1. By clicking on the wrong number, the score will decrease by 1. I hard code the correct number to be 5 in this code.

When I click on end button, the random number will stop generating. However, the score still continues to be able to press which increase/decrease the score. The score must be final once the end button is pressed. I have tried adding a boolean condition of true/false but it does not seem to work at all.

Will appreciate someone to advice me on how to prevent the onClick from working after the end button has been click so that the score can no longer be adjusted. I am looking for a Javascript solution only (no JQuery).

```js
var counter = 0;
var score = 0;
var change;

function start() {
  var totalscoreSpan = document.getElementById("tscore");
  totalscoreSpan.innerHTML = counter;

  rand();
  interval();
}

function rand() {
  var randnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

  var random1Span = document.getElementById("number");
  random1Span.innerText = randnumber;
  document.getElementById("number").onclick = function() {
    if (randnumber == 5) {
      counter += 1;
      document.getElementById("tscore").innerHTML = counter;
    } else {
      counter -= 1;
      document.getElementById("tscore").innerHTML = counter;
    }
  }
}

function interval() {
  change = setInterval(rand, 1000);
}

function end() {
  // End changing number
  clearInterval(change);
}
```

```html
<button onClick="start()">Start</button>
<button onClick="end()">End</button>
<br /><br />
<span style="font: Arial; font-size: 26;">Score: </span><span id="tscore" style="font: Arial; font-size: 26; color: red;"></span>
<br /><br />
<span id="number" style="font: Arial; font-size: 64; color: red;"></span>
```

Comment: Never have an event handler assigned in a function that can be called more than once - move `document.getElementById("number").onclick = function() {` outside the functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you can remove `click` event listener from `#number` or you can check if your `end` button was already clicked.

1st way is to change your `end()` function into something like this:

```js
function end()
{
    document.getElementById('number').removeEventListener('click');
    // End changing number
    clearInterval(change);
}
```

The second way:

1. Add a variable that will be checked every time user clicks on `number`:

```js
let ended = false;
```

2. Change variable in `end()` function:

```js
function end()
{
    ended = true;
    // End changing number
    clearInterval(change);
}
```

3. check if `ended` is true every time user clicks on number:

```js
document.getElementById("number").onclick = function()
{
  if (ended) return;

  // rest of your event listener code goes here...
}
```

Comment: I've just tried your updated code and it works perfectly for me. I can click the number and scoring continues. Probably there's a problem with your browser cache, try to clear it, or disable in Chrome Devtools (if using Chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Changes:

- add **window.onload** to attach onClick event only once, no need to call it on every call of start function
- add **isStarting** variable to detect if he's playing or not
- in **start** function assigne **isStarting** to **true**
- in **end** function assigne **isStarting** to **false**
- make **randnumber** global variable, so can check it from window.onload

```js
var isStarting = false;
var counter = 0;
var score = 0;
var change;
var randnumber;

window.onload = (e) => {
  // run only once .. no need every onStart()
  document.getElementById("number").onclick = function() {
    if (isStarting) {
      if (randnumber == 5) {
        counter += 1;
        document.getElementById("tscore").innerHTML = counter;
      } else {
        counter -= 1;
        document.getElementById("tscore").innerHTML = counter;
      }
    }
  }
};

function start() {
  isStarting = true;
  var totalscoreSpan = document.getElementById("tscore");
  totalscoreSpan.innerHTML = counter;

  rand();
  interval();
}

function rand() {
  randnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

  var random1Span = document.getElementById("number");
  random1Span.innerText = randnumber;

}

function interval() {
  change = setInterval(rand, 1000);
}

function end() {
  isStarting = false;
  // End changing number
  clearInterval(change);
}
```

```html
<button onClick="start()">Start</button>
<button onClick="end()">End</button>
<br /><br />
<span style="font: Arial; font-size: 26;">Score: </span><span id="tscore" style="font: Arial; font-size: 26; color: red;"></span>
<br /><br />
<span id="number" style="font: Arial; font-size: 64; color: red;"></span>
```